# Accessing varible ouside of arrow functions scope

Tags: javascript, discord.js

For some reason I can't set a variable from inside a arrow function that is set outside of it. This is using replit's database. When I send the message containing the embed in the arrow function it works, but it will be in separate embeds.

Here is my code:

```
    ARDB.list().then(keys => {
      const ARListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')

      for (var I=0; I<keys.length; I++) {
        ARDB.get(keys[I]).then(value => {
          ARListEmbed.addField("["+(I+1)+"]"+" "+keys[I], value, true);
        }));
      };

      message.channel.send(ARListEmbed);
    });
```

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: I tried debugging to no avail, the ARListEmbed sends fine it's just not got the feilds added so no error.

Comment: Do `let ARListEmbed;` in the global scope, add the definition inside the function, this will hoist the value onto the variable and will still be accessible to inner scopes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! But I seemed to fix this myself.

Here is the code that worked somehow.

```
   ARDB.list().then(keys => {
      const Length = keys.length;
      let Index = 0;

      let ARListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('9NK Discord Server Auto Responses:')
        .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=OfficialRickAstley')

      for (var I=0; I<keys.length; I++) {
        let Key = keys[I];

        ARDB.get(keys[I]).then(value => {
          Index++;

          ARListEmbed.addField("["+(Index)+"]"+" "+Key, value, true);

          if (Index == Length) {
            message.channel.send(ARListEmbed);
          };
        });
      };
    });
```

This code works because Index can be changed within the arrow function and keeps it's changed value when the for loop loops again but ouside of the loop it says it's original self (0). So I send the message when Index == keys length.